# Draw a top bordered tip with CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am trying to draw a tip in CSS.

I have "middle success" so far, the only problem is that, depending on DIV width, the tip sometimes are not in the center position.

#### What I want:

[image]

#### My code so far:

```css
.logo {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
}

.line {
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}

.line.top,
.line.bottom {
  width: 90%;
}

.line.top {
  margin: 0 auto 4px;
}

.line.bottom {
  margin: 4px auto 0;
}

.angle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  left: 46%; // I think my problem is here!
}

.angle .line.left,
.angle .line.right {
  width: 20px;
}

.angle .line.left {
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: 7px;
}

.angle .line.right {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin: -7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <div class="angle">
    <div class="line left"></div>
    <div class="line right"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="line top"></div>
  
  MY TEXT
  
  <div class="line bottom"></div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this?

I thought setting **.angle** `width: 30px` and `margin: 0 auto`, but it have `position: absolute`, so it is not possible.

*Ps: LESS can be used.*

Comment: how about javascript? And can you specify a div width in css? if so you can calculate position of tip using sass/less

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need of so many elements. Just use `.logo` element and its pseudo classes. and use `letter-spacing` css property to give space between the letters. (*or use the exact font, if you know the name*)

**CSS**

```
.logo {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-align: center;
    height: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 2em;
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.logo::after, .logo::before {
    content:"";
    border-width: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.logo::after {
    border-width: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
}
.logo::before {
    border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle - using CSS**](http://jsfiddle.net/x1a0jbcf/3/)

[**Working Fiddle - using SCSS**](http://jsfiddle.net/x1a0jbcf/2/)

Comment: I would create it with a single bordered and rotated pseudo element that will work on any background color / image / gradient - [like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/8uv71j2r/)

Comment: @misterManSam yeah I know that trick but I like this because it supports IE8 too (_anyway, who cares about it now_). It just I got used to it :)

Comment: To be super pedantic, IE8 would need a single colon (`:`) as it doesn't recognise the double syntax (`::`) and IE8 wouldn't recognise the `transform` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Nested Triangles!

```css
.outer {
    border: 40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 40px solid black;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner {
    border: 36px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 36px solid white;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -32px;
    left: -36px;   
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just rotate a div and add a border to it. Then using z-indexing put it behind a div with just a top and bottom border holding your text. Might look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html{padding: 10px;}
.triangle {
        width: 10%;
        height: 10%;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        z-index: -1;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 45%;
    }
    .textBox {
        height: 40px;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        background: white;
        z-index: 2;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo">
      <div class="triangle"></div>

      <div class="textBox">
      MY TEXT
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
    margin-top:70px;
}
h2{
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #88b7d5;
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
}
```

See working demo [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Coding_killer/ooghndcv/)